# Зафиксировать подсказку при наведении мыши на объект

Tags: javascript

Есть скрипт на JS выводящий подсказку.
Хочу его сделать статическим, так как пользователям удобнее читать подсказки, можно по объекту поёрзать мышкой (имхо).
Одним слово по вертикали сделал чтобы он стоял на месте, а вот по горизонтали как-то не разобрался.

Как сделать так, чтобы подсказка не двигалась за курсором мыши, а покзывалась один раз и оставалась неподвижной?

Его код можно протестировать тут:
https://jsfiddle.net/1uvd1juq/2/

Вот что у меня пока что есть.

```
   <html>
    <title>Всплывающая подсказка</title>

    <style>
    #floatTip {
    position: absolute; /* Абсолютное позиционирование */
    width: 250px; /* Ширина блока */

    display: none; /* Прячем от показа */
    border: 1px solid #666666; /* Параметры рамки */
    padding: 4px; /* Поля вокруг  текста */
    font-family: sans-serif; /* Рубленый шрифт */
    font-size: 9pt; /* Размер  шрифта */
    color: #333; /* Цвет текста */
    background: #ffffbb; /* Цвет фона */
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow:10px 10px 5px 0px #bbbbbb;
    margin-top:-150px;
    }
    </style>
     </head>
     <body>

    <script>
    document.onmousemove = moveTip;
    function moveTip(e) {
      floatTipStyle = document.getElementById("floatTip").style;
      w = 250; // Ширина подсказки

      // Для браузера IE6-8
      if (document.all)  { 
        x = event.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft; 
        y = event.clientY + document.body.scrollTop; 

      // Для остальных браузеров
      } else   { 
        //x = 0; // Координата X курсора
        //y = 0; // Координата Y курсора
        x = e.pageX; // Координата X курсора
        y = e.pageY; // Координата Y курсора
      }

      // Показывать слой справа от курсора 
      if ((x + w + 10) < document.body.clientWidth) { 
        floatTipStyle.left = x + 'px';

      // Показывать слой слева от курсора
      } else { 
        floatTipStyle.left = x - w + 'px';
      }

      // Положение от  верхнего края окна браузера
         //floatTipStyle.top = y + 20 + 'px';
        //floatTipStyle.top = y + 20 + 'px';
    }

    function toolTip(msg) {
      floatTipStyle = document.getElementById("floatTip").style;
      if (msg) {
        // Выводим текст подсказки
        document.getElementById("floatTip").innerHTML = msg;
        // Показываем подсказку
        floatTipStyle.display = "block";
      } else { 
        // Прячем подсказку
        floatTipStyle.display = "none";
      } 
    }

         </script>
      <br><br><br><br><br><br><br>  <br><br><br><br><br>

         Всякий разный текст типа "рыбы". Ещё текст. И ещё <img src="https://pp.vk.me/c319926/v319926670/2fe9/6puUZQ99oc8.jpg" alt="Фотография" 
      onMouseOver="toolTip('Просто кнопка и подсказка к ней<br>Работает тег <b>br</b><hr> и даже <b>hr</b>. А так же <b>b</b> и <b>i</b> текст с <b>b</b> - <b>жирный</b>, текст с <b>i</b> <i>наклонный</i>. ')" onMouseOut="toolTip()">



      <div id="floatTip"></div>
     </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам просто надо убрать обработчик `document.onmousemove = moveTip;` который реагирует на каждое движение мыши.
Проще всего на основе вашего кода вызывать `moveTip()` один раз в обработчике `onMouseOver`.

Надо передать объект события в обработчик

```
onMouseOver="toolTip(event, 'Просто кнопка и подсказка к ней<br>Работает тег...');
```

Поменять заголовок функции вызвать в ней `moveTip(event)`

```
function toolTip(event, msg) {
  floatTipStyle = document.getElementById("floatTip").style;
  if (msg) {
    // Выводим текст подсказки
    document.getElementById("floatTip").innerHTML = msg;
    // Показываем подсказку
   moveTip(event); // перемещаем элемент 1 раз
    floatTipStyle.display = "block";
  } else { 
    // Прячем подсказку
    floatTipStyle.display = "none";
  } 
}
```

Comment: Спасибо!  
[7 символов нужно...]

Comment: @I_CaR пожалуйста. Мне нравится ваш способ обходить запреты системы ))

Answer (score 0):

Я ещё вот так это реализовал (совсем др.способ)
Наверное корявый?
https://jsfiddle.net/pavpyLdn/

```
<script>


    intTip = 2;
function swapTAG()
{
switch (intTip)
    {
 case 1:

   ToolTip_1.innerHTML = "текст с подсказкой";
   intTip = 2;

   return(false);
case 2:

   ToolTip_1.innerHTML = "Тут текст с подсказкой<div id='ToolTip_core'> Подсказка !!!</div>";
   intTip = 1;   
   return(false); 
}
}


intTip = 2;
function clearTAG()
{
   ToolTip_1.innerHTML = "Тут текст с подсказкой";
   intTip = 2;
   return(false);

}


</script>
<br>
    <br>


     <span style="font: normal 14px 'Trebuchet MS';">   
   Тут обычный текст. <span name="spoiler_01" onMouseOver="swapTAG()" onMouseOut="clearTAG()" id="ToolTip_1">Тут текст с подсказкой</span>. А тут опять обычный текст.</span>
```

Comment: Оригинально, но уж очень криво. Предыдущий способ гораздо лучше, хотя и в нем надо бы обработчики добавлять не в разметке, а скриптом при загрузке страницы. Тут у вас еще есть минус в том, подсказка не выравнивается (если на краю страницы, то половина будет не видна). Да и для такой подсказки, лучше использовать стандартный `<span title="Подсказка">Текст с подсказкой</span>`